# Use the same TemplateView for create and update

Tags: python, django

I have this TemplateView:

```
class DamageEntry(TemplateView):
    template_name = "damage/damageadd.html"

    def get(self, request):
        general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
        form = DamageEntryForm()
        args = {'form': form,
                'general': general,
                }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        general = General.objects.get(pk=1)
        form = DamageEntryForm(request.POST)
        form.non_field_errors()

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)

            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                post.user = request.user


            post.userip = get_client_ip(request)  # το IP του χρήστη

            location = get_cocation(post.lat, post.lng)

            post.location = location
            post.formatted_address= location.formatted_address


            post.entry_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
            post.save()

            form = DamageEntryForm()
            args = {'form': form,
                    'general': general
                    }
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('damage/add/')
           
        else:
             print('form is not valid')
             print(form.errors)
            # form = DamageEntryForm()
             args = {'form': form,
                    'general': general
                    }
             return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

It works fine for create new record.
I want to use thw same view for update, because of the extra code on Post section.

I use this URL for update:

```
# /damage/damage/list/1
url(r'damage/list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DamageEntry.as_view(), name="damage-by-id"),
```

Can I do this? How can I pass pk for create and update record?

Comment: What happens when you try to post data?

Comment: My thought: you can do that but you need to use model form instead of normal form, so you can pass a instance of a model while creating a form

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish what you're trying to do in one view, at least not with a pk as your reference. I think a slug will suit your needs better. You can then search for the slug and if not found you can create the object. however this means everytime you make a typo in your search of the slug it will create and add that typo to the db. I would make two views in your case (querying by pk).

Comment: Post works fine. But I have extra code for userip , latitude etc. I want to run the same on updates. I don't get the slug method , I am new to django. Can you give me a link to look? Thanks

Comment: I use a ModelForm as form. How can I solve my problem with model form?

Comment: If I use an update form like this

`class DamageListEntry(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Damage
    template_name = "damage/damageadd.html"
    form_class = DamageEntryForm
    success_url = 'damage/list/' `

can I add a POST section to run the code I want?